# How to use Hash on the query builder results in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is my code

```
$all = $this->find()
        ->select(['ProductCircles.id', 'ProductCircles.type', 'ProductCircles.name'])
        ->order(['ProductCircles.type'])
        ->all()
        ->toArray();

        Log::write('error', $all);

        $all = Hash::combine($all, '{n}.ProductCircles.id', '{n}.ProductCircles.name', '{n}.ProductCircles.type');
```

The `$all` is an array of ProductCircle entities.

However, the Hash combine is unable to act on the data as I expected.

Please advise.

`$all` was expected to be an array of ProductCircle entities:

```
2015-03-15 08:04:36 Error: Array
(
    [0] => App\Model\Entity\ProductCircle Object
        (
            [_accessible:protected] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 1
                    [type] => 1
                    [product_count] => 1
                    [products_in_circles] => 1
                )

            [_properties:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 27
                    [type] => MATERIAL
                    [name] => Wood
                )

            [_original:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_hidden:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_virtual:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_className:protected] => App\Model\Entity\ProductCircle
            [_dirty:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_new:protected] => 
            [_errors:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_registryAlias:protected] => ProductCircles
        )
```

Which is what I expected.

What I want to do with the Hash::combine is to get an array of arrays like this:

```
$result:
    [
        [MATERIAL] => [
                [27] => [
                        Wood
                ]
        ]
```

Comment: _the Hash combine is unable to act on the data as I expected._ - You need to be specific. Show a sample of $al (from the find)l and what you expect the final result to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use Hash, but the collection methods that are built into the query object:

```
$combined = $this->find()
    ->select(['ProductCircles.id', 'ProductCircles.type', 'ProductCircles.name'])
    ->order(['ProductCircles.type'])
    ->combine('id', 'name', 'type')
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Your answer worked. I have to know: a) where is this combine method stated in the cookbook? b) why is it that I need not add a `->all()` to the query? c) If you noticed the Hash article in the cookbook for cake3, http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html#Cake\Utility\Hash::extract, it actually suggests using the Hash directly on the query object. Is that correct?

Comment: It is here, read all the examples so you understand why it works and what are all other methods that can be used: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#the-query-object

Comment: In that case, I think the cake3 book examples on Hash need some changes. I will make some changes to it later this weekend.

Comment: Is that right that i cant do this `Hash::combine($q, '{n}.id', '{n}', '{n}.group_id')` with ORM?

Comment: Answering my own: I can have callback inside. `(new Collection($row->layout_boxes))->combine('id', function ($entity) { return $entity; }, 'col')->toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on José's answer (and using the `extract()` because that's the one I needed):

```
$query = $this->MyTable->find('all', [
    'contain' => [
        'ProductCircles',
    ],
    // ...
]);
return $query->all()->extract('ProductCircles.name');
```

More info: [book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::extract](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::extract)